# this.setState() cannot seem to take a non immediate function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React class:

```
            class App extends React.Component{
                // Make a constructor to hold attributes in memory.
                constructor(props){
                    // This line is needed to instantiate
                    super(props)
                    // Attributes when this object is init for first time.
                    this.state = {
                        count:0
                    }
                }

                render(){
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                            <button onClick={this.count}>Count!</button>
                        </div>
                    
                    );
                }
                // Set the count attribute to point to some nameless function.
                count = () => {
                    //  a built in method to update state of an object.
                    // setState takes a state and does the following.  
                    this.setState(state => ({
                        count:state.count + 1   
                    })

                    )
                }
            }
```

this.setState correctly takes an anonymous function. However, when I try to pass in a non annonymous function like so, i get thrown an error:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: state
rethrowCaughtError — react-dom.development.js:321:

```
                count = () => {
                    //  a built in method to update state of an object.
                    // setState takes a state and does the following.  
                    function some_func(state){
                        count:state.count + 1   
                    }
                    this.setState(some_func(state))
                    
                }
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You're passing the result of **calling** `some_func()`. Also `some_func()` is wrong anyway, as posted; the body should be something like `state.count++;`.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi - the state is defined in the constructor

Comment: @Pointy Am I correct in saying that the 1st example which works properly, we are passing in a function which takes a variable `state`? And, since setState() expects a function, rather than the result of a function, it is wise to pass in anonymous functions into setState()?

Comment: You can pass any kind of function you want. The problem with the second example is that the code is passing `undefined`.

Comment: @rayhatfield it's valid syntax but it doesn't do anything. `count:` is interpreted as a statement label.

Comment: @Pointy Ah. Okay. I never use that and often forget that it exists. Still, I don’t think that was the intent here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you pass the `state` in `some_function` when calling plus in your function you did not return anything. Try this out:

```
count = () => {
    //  a built in method to update state of an object.
    // setState takes a state and does the following.
    function some_func(state){
      return {...state, count: state.count + 1}
    }
    this.setState(some_func(this.state))
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has to return an Object. Like Zahid Hasan has suggested, that's another approach.

**Options 1:**

Your function must return a value, whose type is an object representing the entire state.

```
count = () => {
    function some_func(state){
      return {...state, count: ++state.count}
    }
    this.setState(some_func(this.state))
};
```

**Option 2:**

Your function must return a value, whose type is an Object bust only represents a certain property within `state`, in this case would be `count`:

```
count = () => {
    function some_func(state){
      return {count: ++state.count};
    }

    this.setState({...state, ...some_func(this.state)})
};
```

---

The key here is: your function must return the new value.